# Error creating vCore-based Elastic Pool using Powershell on Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, pool

I have already created the server and I am using the following code:

```
New-AzureRmSqlElasticPool -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname -ServerName $servername -ElasticPoolName "ElasticPool071" -VCore 1 -Edition "GeneralPurpose" -ComputeGeneration "Gen5" -InformationVariable ee  -debug -ErrorVariable ErrorMessages
```

the ouput I am recieving is>>

```
Set-AzureRmSqlElasticPool : An unexpected error occured while processing the request. Tracking ID: 'a2936090-e7af-4203-be1c-9425932055f3'
At line:1 char:2
+  Set-AzureRmSqlElasticPool  -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname -Se ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmSqlElasticPool], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.ElasticPool.Cmdlet.SetAzureSqlElasticPool

DEBUG: AzureQoSEvent: CommandName - Set-AzureRmSqlElasticPool; IsSuccess - False; Duration - 00:00:26.8490006; Exception - Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: An unexpected error occured while processing the request. Tracking ID: 'a2936090-e7af-
4203-be1c-9425932055f3'
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.ElasticPoolsOperations.<BeginUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.ElasticPoolsOperations.<UpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.ElasticPoolsOperationsExtensions.<UpdateAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.ElasticPoolsOperationsExtensions.Update(IElasticPoolsOperations operations, String resourceGroupName, String serverName, String elasticPoolName, ElasticPoolUpdate parameters)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.ElasticPool.Services.AzureSqlElasticPoolAdapter.UpsertElasticPool(AzureSqlElasticPoolModel model)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.ElasticPool.Cmdlet.SetAzureSqlElasticPool.PersistChanges(IEnumerable`1 entity)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Common.AzureSqlCmdletBase`2.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<ExecuteCmdlet>b__0()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ConfirmAction(String processMessage, String target, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Common.AzureSqlCmdletBase`2.ExecuteCmdlet()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord();
```

Could you please help!?

Comment: Why the command is `New-AzureRmSqlElasticPool` but the error shows it's `Set-AzureRmSqlElasticPool`?

Answer (score 0):

For Gen 5 Compute Generation, you must allocate a minimum of 2 vCores. For Gen 4 you can allocate 1 vCore.

[Azure SQL Database vCore-based purchasing model limits for elastic pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-vcore-resource-limits-elastic-pools#generation-5-compute-platform)
[SQL Database pricing options](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/elastic/)